# Is there harm in calling reboot from a sh file running under su from an android app?

Tags: android, sh

Using GScript for example, is there any harm that can come to a phone or tablet if the reboot command is run from a shell script inside of an android app? All based on the device being rooted, and the app having su permission from the user, etc...

Comment: Insomuch as Android is Linux, there shouldn't be any trouble: files will be closed and pending data written. I have no idea how running apps might respond to that. I'd imagine even normal reboots could confuse *some* of those.

Comment: We use devices in house, and sometimes device rotate between users so we need to wipe all personal data using scripts and then reboot the device for the final reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I would no brainer send sync before reboot.

```
sync && reboot
```

Comment: [sync invocation - GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sync-invocation.html) has this:
`sync writes any data buffered in memory out to disk. This can include (but is not limited to) modified superblocks, modified inodes, and delayed reads and writes. This must be implemented by the kernel; The sync program does nothing but exercise the sync system call.
...`

Comment: This makes me happy, but its still not clear if the sync, reboot combo will push up to the app / service levels as cleanly as physically shutting down the device (as doing that seems to take a bit longer).

Comment: thank you - I searched for variations on the question "how to reboot from a command line inside an Android tablet?" - it's just `reboot` without the `sudo` or nothing